# single file upload using nodeJs multer not working with Angular frontend

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload, multer

I'm trying to do single file upload using multer. Although I'm able to upload a file manually just using node in the relevant folder, I cannot sync it with my Angular frontend. I created a folder called uploads in the node backend folder where the files are supposed to get uploaded. Also I need to upload the file within a form and pass it to a api where it should take the file along with other parameters also.

My node backend code which is working is below:

```
const multer = require('multer')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({

destination: function(req, file, cb) {

cb(null, './uploads/')

},

filename: function(req, file, cb) {

cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname)

}

})

const upload = multer({storage: storage})
```

**node route code**

```
app.post(baseUrl+'/create', upload.single('imagePath'), blogController.createBlog);
```

**Below is my Angular Component code which is not working:**

```
selectImage(event) {

if(event.target.files.length > 0){

const file = event.target.files[0];

this.images = file;

}

}

public createBlog(): any {

const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('imagePath', this.images);

let blogData = {

title: this.blogTitle,

description: this.blogDescription,

blogBody: this.blogBodyHtml,

category: this.blogCategory,

imagePath: this.imagePath

} //end blogData

console.log(blogData);

this.blogHttpService.createBlog(blogData).subscribe(...calling the node route)
```

**Frontend HTML Code:**

```
<div>

<input type="file" name="imagePath" (change)="selectImage($event)" />

</div>
```

Comment: So, when you say it is not working, what is the behavior? So `blogData` gets in `blogHttpService.createBlog` to an `http` post right?; which is an observable (can also mean timing is off). Alway add an rxjs `catchError` to http call. More description of what the Angular behavior is needed.

Comment: In the above code you didn't invoked function **createBlog()** in **selectImage()**, Is it just a copy/paste mistake or you really didn't invoked it ?

Comment: @SameerKhan I didn't ivoke createBlog() within selectImage() intentionally because in doing to the api will get called immediately even before the user fills up the whole blog and presses the button to post

Comment: @ThomasCayne when I'm testing the express route using tools like postman, the image is getting uploaded in the relevant folder. But when I'm trying to integrate it with angular frontend it is returning internal server error 500 and unable to upload the file